# Is the blinding effect of Glitterdust effective on mindless undead?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, undead

We have just started a new pure Pathfinder campaign and I'm playing a Witch, one of only two arcane casters in the party (the other is a knowledge-based Bard). It looks like the campaign might involve a lot of undead, and possibly vampires, so our spellcasting effectiveness may be a bit of a problem.

I am looking for a couple of second-level spells and was considering [Glitterdust](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glitterdust), but I'm not sure how effective it will be on undead. Can you blind things like zombies and skeletons using it?

Answer (score 23):

There's no fictional reason why the blinding effect wouldn't be effective on zombies and skeletons: they have to visually sense you *somehow*, and there's nothing in their descriptions that indicates that they have the power to see through barriers and obscuring effects.

Rule-wise, *glitterdust* doesn't make any special exceptions for undead of any kind, and there are no abilities on [zombies](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/zombie) or [skeletons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/skeleton-medium) that would make them immune to the blinding effect, and the [undead features](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Undead) don't include anything that interacts with *glitterdust* in any relevant way.

Comment: This [SKR essay](http://www.seankreynolds.com/rpgfiles/rants/undeadseethroughillusions.html) is a rant against the idea that undead somehow have different vision than regular monsters.

Answer (score 8):

Glitterdust is not a mind-affecting effect, a disease, a poison so yes, it will work on mindless undead.